# Azure data factory - changing URL for HTTP linked service?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Forgive me if this is a relatively simple question (I have just picked up Azure Data Factory today) however I have a linked service which points to a hosted .CSV file which I import into a SQL server. The URL I currently use is as follows. The date part of the URL is dynamic.

http://download.test.com/exampledownload-2021-07-01.csv

I have added some logic which dynamically populates the date part of the link to get the latest file, however I have ran into some issues today as the provider has added another part to the URL..

http://download.test.com/**32433**/exampledownload-2021-07-01.csv

The number part of the URL is completely random (so I can't really write anything to work around this)

Is there anything in else in ADF that could be used to deal with this? Or would I need to look at other programming languages to find a fix?

Thank you

Comment: Your question seems to repeat itself. Could you take another look and clarify the question?

Comment: If the number is random how are you being notified of it so you can get the csv from it ?

Comment: its a link on a public website.

It used to exclude the number and just have the date of the file as the URL (it was always the first date of the current month so it was easy to create this dynamically in ADF)

The pipeline runs once a month and this month it has failed due to the link changing to include the numbers